# What is a more efficient method of retrieving hierarchical overrides in SQL than UNION ALL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to build out a capability to set default values at appropriate levels in a hierarchy (from client down to employee) and to allow for defaults to be set at the highest level possible (to minimize unnecessary data).  This capability will be exercised frequently (thousands of times a day) and the underlying configuration data will be too volatile to meaningfully cache.

I know I can use the following statement to get back what I need (by taking the first row) but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient statement to accomplish the same goal.

This is a simplified example of the type of data I am working with.

[image]

In case the image isn't appearing inline it is here - !https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWgnb.jpg

The code below represents the UNION ALL statement with two different sets of parameters to show the underlying behavior which is working correctly (and is indexed appropriately) but I want to make sure I am not missing something that can make it more efficient.

```
DECLARE @ClientID VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @OfficeID VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @DepartmentID VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @EmployeeID VARCHAR(2
```

This set of parameters will return the employee specific override record (SettingID 400) first because there is a fully qualified entry for this employee,

```
SELECT @ClientID = 'Acme', @OfficeID = 'Chicago', @DepartmentID = 'Finance', @EmployeeID = 'JDOE'
```

This set of parameters will return the Office specific Override record (SettingID 200) first because there is a qualified entry for this Office (but not department or employee)

```
SELECT @ClientID = 'Acme', @OfficeID = 'Chicago', @DepartmentID = 'IT', @EmployeeID = 'JSMITH'
```

Here is the query I am currently executing. . .

```
SELECT HierarchyOverrideID, SettingID FROM HierarchyOverride WHERE ClientID = @ClientID AND OfficeID = @OfficeID AND DepartmentID = @DepartmentID AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
UNION ALL 
SELECT HierarchyOverrideID, SettingID FROM HierarchyOverride WHERE ClientID = @ClientID AND OfficeID = @OfficeID AND DepartmentID = @DepartmentID  AND EmployeeID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT HierarchyOverrideID, SettingID FROM HierarchyOverride WHERE ClientID = @ClientID AND OfficeID = @OfficeID AND DepartmentID IS NULL  AND EmployeeID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT HierarchyOverrideID, SettingID FROM HierarchyOverride WHERE ClientID = @ClientID AND OfficeID IS NULL AND DepartmentID IS NULL  AND EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but I'd argue that this data is structured badly.

Presumably you have `Client`, `Office`, `Department`, and `Employee` tables, all of which have relations to each other. If you put the `SettingId` in each of those tables, you could write a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE (e.settingid,
                 d.settingid,
                 o.settingid,
                 c.setting_id) as settingid
FROM   client c
       LEFT JOIN office o
          ON c.clientid = o.clientid AND o.officeid = @officeid
       LEFT JOIN department d
          ON c.officeid = d.officeid AND d.departmentid = @departmentid
       LEFT JOIN employee e
          ON d.departmentid = e.departmentid AND e.employeeid = @employeeid
WHERE  c.clientid = @clientid
```

Admittedly, I'm making pretty big assumptions 1) about what your data structure looks like and 2) that you change that structure at this stage. Given these assumptions, I think things would be significantly easier using this pattern.

Comment: The reality is that the need is more complicated than this with many settings of different types therefore we cannot accommodate this method.

Answer (score 0):

Next solution should give you the setting you want to have without further processing in code, but I can not predict the terms of execution time.

```
SELECT HierarchyOverrideId, SettingId
FROM ( SELECT HierarchyOverrideId, SettingId, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE 
                                WHEN EmployeeId is not null THEN 1
                                WHEN DepartmentId is not null THEN 2
                                WHEN OfficeId is not null THEN 3
                                ELSE 4
                              END )
    FROM dbo.HierarchyOverride
    WHERE (EmployeeId = @EmployeeID OR EmployeeId is NULL)
     AND (DepartmentId   = @DepartmentId  OR DepartmentId  is NULL)
     AND (OfficeID  = @OfficeID  OR OfficeID is NULL)
     AND ClientId = @ClientID
) as a
WHERE a.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

does this cover it?

```
SELECT HierarchyOverrideID, SettingID 
  FROM HierarchyOverride 
 WHERE ClientID = @ClientID 
   AND (    (   OfficeID = @OfficeID                        and DepartmentID = @DepartmentID and (EmployeeID = @EmployeeID or EmployeeID IS NULL ) )
         OR ( ( OfficeID = @OfficeID OR  OfficeID is null ) and DepartmentID is null         and  EmployeeID IS NULL ) 
       )
```